# Samsung Devices API 12 does not Dial code automatically

Tags: android, shell, adb, samsung-mobile

We are trying to dial the code

```
  "*%2306%23" = "*#06#"
```

through the adb command to fetch the information about the IMEI

```
 adb -s "DEVICE SERIAL" shell am start -a android.intent.action.DIAL -d tel:*%2306%23
```

The connected device shows the code on the screen but doesn't auto-dial. But, when we try to dial manually it's working fine.

The device is connected and the developer option is enabled.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent that you are sending only opens the dialer app and enters the number, it does not dial. In order to dial you have to press the call button - `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_CALL`, but...
you are not dialing a regular number, you want to enter some code, so you have to open the dialer and enter the code symbol by symbol:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.DIAL
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_STAR
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_POUND
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_0
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_6
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_POUND
```

Comment: This one is good solution to add characters one by one. thanks